# $G' = [A, B]$ if $G = AB$, where $A,B$ are abelian.

Tags: finite-groups, abelian-groups

Suppose that $G = AB$, where $A$ and $B$ are abelian subgroups. Show
that $G' = [A, B]$.

Showing that $[A,B] \subseteq G'$ is simple enough, but how do I show reverse inclusion?

Comment: What is $G'$ in this context?

Comment: $G'$ is the derived subgroup of $G$, i.e., the group generated by the set $\{x^{-1}y^{-1}xy:x \in G,y \in G\}$.

Comment: A simple method would be to show that $G/[A,B]$ is abelian. Some commutator identities could be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $[x,y] = x^{-1} y^{-1} xy$ and $x^y = y^{-1} xy$. Then we have the identities $[x, yz] = [x,z] [x,y]^z$, $[xy,z] = [x,z]^y [y,z]$ and $[x,y]^g = [x^g, y^g]$.

For example by applying the first two identities, you can see that it is enough to show that the set $\{[a,b] : a \in A, b \in B\}$ is closed under conjugation.

Let $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. Then using the identities above, for $a' \in A$ and $b' \in B$ we have

$[a,b]^{a'} = [a, b^{a'}] = [a, a^{''} b^*] = [a, b^*]$

$[a,b]^{b'} = [a^{b'}, b] = [b^{''} a^*, b] = [a^*, b]$

where $b^{a'} = a^{''} b^*$ and $a^{b'} = b^{''} a^*$ with $a^{''}, a^* \in A$ and $b^{''}, b^* \in B$.

---

For a reference and more, see Satz 1 in the following article.

> Itô, Noboru. *Über das Produkt von zwei abelschen Gruppen*. Math. Z. 62 (1955), 400–401. [link](https://eudml.org/doc/169505)

Comment: You could simply transcribe the proof if it is a "short manipulation"! It is *always* better for posts to be self-contained.

Comment: It's very difficult for me to follow this, try as I might. Could you please give me a very short proof? I think I get the general idea, but it's still not clear.

Comment: @J.G.: Ok, done